# Why I am unable to initialize Service Registry( Hibernate) via Servlets?

Tags: java, html, hibernate, tomcat, servlets

```
public static void main(String args[])  {

System.out.println("<<++++++++INITIALIZED+++++++>>");

    final Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
    final StandardServiceRegistryBuilder builder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
            .applySettings(configuration.getProperties());

    // Session Factory
 factory = configuration
            .buildSessionFactory(builder.build());

    // Open Session
    session = factory.openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();


}

public static void  checkNow(String name,String email,String pass,String phone){
     System.out.println("<<++++++++INITIALIZED+++++++>>");

    main(null);

    System.out.println("<<++++++++INITIALIZED+++++++>>");
    Transaction  tx=  session.beginTransaction();
    User user = new User();
    user.setpersonal_Name(name);
    user.setpersonal_Email(email);
    user.setpersonal_Password(pass);
    user.setpersonal_Phone(phone);
    tx.begin();
    System.out.println("<<+++++++SAVING++++++>>>");
    session.save(user);
    tx.commit();
    session.close();
    factory.close();
}
```

In this code User properties coming from linked html Servlet and from that Servlet I am calling a method of concrete class i.e "CheckData.java",If I run this code with main method its working fine Table created and If I run this from whole process that is, from Web (Appache Tomcat) Its giving me error of ClassNotFoundException ServiceRegistry.Solution required ASAP.[This is my Project Explorer having some html,css and java classes / servlets.Dynamic Web Project Using Appache Tomcat Server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ejg9j.png),[My Exception Screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y32Md.png)

Comment: Unable to view the excetion screenshot

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y32Md.png

Answer (score 0):

Actually The Problem Was with Libraries where I was putting them

See my Project Explorer I have put them in just right place but in case of Dynamic Web Project , We have to define Libraries not only as a "Build Path" but also in lib folder Under "Web Content" Folder too .

Thanks Everyone who at least viewed Once